# Imported zbrush mesh cannot be parented with automated weighted

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, zbrush

I did a mesh in Zbrush, sculpt it with level subdivision 5. Send the mesh to Blender with GoB, automatically GoB import in blender Level 1 mesh (not a problem at all), so want parenting the mesh to my Rigify generated rig, well, this was fine sometime before (I think until release 2.76), but now it took hours or cannot do at all, for parenting the mesh (composed by all quads). Why? Cannot understand what is the problem.

Comment: If you want to make a test use this sample file, is not the some I use, but the result is the some: https://www.mediafire.com/file/a6ylqt59rvyqgq4/Weights%20error.zip

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main problem is your rig and your mesh don't line up very well (at least in the file you provided). I would suggest starting by making sure each bone is where it should be. If the bones aren't close to any geometry blender is going to have a really hard time determining which bone should control each vertex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cannot post the actual mesh, is a model done for a client and cannot share. The result doesn't change at all if lining better the bones with mesh, you can try to position better the bones (on the blender scene there is also the base rigging), will have the same slow result.